# Python's CSVReader seems to be seperating on periods

Tags: python, pandas, csv, validation

Interesting problem, I'm using python's CSVreader to read comma delimited data from a UTF-8 formatted CSV file. It appears the reader is truncating column names when it encounters a period.

For example, here is a sample of my column names.

```
time,b12.76org2101.xz,b12.75org2001.xz,b11.72ogg8090.xy
```

Here's how I'm reading this data

```py
    def parseCSV(inputData):
     file_to_open = inputData
     with open(file_to_open) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        headerLine = True
        line = []
        for row in csv_reader:
          //column manipulation code here
```

And here's how CSVReader interprets those column names

```
time,76org2101,75org2001,72ogg8090
```

Here's the important bit, the code I shared is the first thing in the program that touches that CSV file. After the code has finished execution I can also verify that the CSV file itself is unchanged. The problem must lie with how CSVReader interprets periods but I'm not sure what the fix is

Here's another interesting find. Later in the program I use Pandas to read a list of identical names from a column in another file.

The data is formatted as follows

```
COLUMN_NAMES
b12.76org2101.xz,
b12.75org2001.xz,
b11.72ogg8090.xy,
```

Where COLUMN_NAMES is the CSV's header and the items below are rows.

You can see the code I use to read these values here.

```
data = pandas.read_csv(file_to_open)

Headers = data['COLUMN_NAMES'].tolist()
```

And this is how Pandas interprets those rows

```
76org2101
75org2001
72ogg8090
```

The Data is exactly the same, and we see exactly the same behavior! The column names with periods are truncated in exactly the same way.

So what's up? Because both Pandas and CSVReader have identical issues I'm tempted to think this is a python problem, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any ideas are appreciated!

EDIT: The issue was with my code, I was reading the wrong files which incidentally happened to have the same column names as my expected files, just without anything before or after the periods. What're the odds!

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: Version 0.24.2 running on python 3.6.3

Comment: What happens if you run my second set of code?

Comment: Hmm, appears to run just fine. So the issue must be within my code, shoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.__version__` `'0.23.0'` and `python` version `3.6.5`, I get the expected results:

```
print(pd.read_csv('test.csv'))

       COLUMN_NAMES
0  b12.76org2101.xz
1  b12.75org2001.xz
2  b11.72ogg8090.xy

headers = pd.read_csv('test.csv')['COLUMN_NAMES'].tolist()

print(headers)

['b12.76org2101.xz', 'b12.75org2001.xz', 'b11.72ogg8090.xy']
```

It also works if those values are columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=headers).to_csv('test1.csv', index=None)

print(pd.read_csv('test1.csv'))

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [b12.76org2101.xz, b12.75org2001.xz, b11.72ogg8090.xy]
Index: []
```

Maybe try updating your version of `python`?